# How to extract spider.exe file from XP CD

Tags: 10.04

I am new to Ubuntu (have 10.04 only installed, no dual system), and I wish to add the XP version of spider Solitaire to Wine.  I have an old XP installation CD.

What is the procedure for extracting the spider.exe file from the CD?

Comment: It seems to me it is a better fit for windows related question, because the main task is extracting spider.exe from XP CD

Comment: if you feel any of these answers "answerd" your question please accept one of them thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary to use the windows version:

> It's in default gnome-games installation!  Try AisleRiot Solitaire and change game /ctrl+o/ to spider  I like it more then pySol

from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=517296)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to extract them from a CD.
 
but here is a howto from a installed windows XP.

Navigate to

```
C:\windows\system32\
```

And copy these files

```
cards.dll
freecell.exe
mshearts.exe
sol.exe
spider.chm
spider.exe
spider.hlp
winmine.exe
```

And save them to your /home/USERNAME/spider?? folder.
and then run spider.exe for spider solitaire.

**Source**:

- [How to get the XP version of Spider Solitaire? - Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-gaming/how-to-get-the-xp-version-of-spider-solitaire/b8fc2633-bed0-465f-99bb-cfd97299221d)